# Forms: Subcategory based on Category

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to make a form using two drop down select menus: one to select the category, the other to select a subcategory. I am trying to make it so the subcategory options are based on which category they select first, I don't know where to begin on this and a google search is leaving me empty handed. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript or a library like jQuery to do this. You can start by Googling something like "javascript related dropdown".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:
Note that this is only using html and pure javascript. Yes you can use JQuery too.

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function dropdownlist(listindex)
{

document.formname.subcategory.options.length = 0;

switch (listindex)
{
    case "category1" :
        document.formname.subcategory.options[0]=new Option("subcategory1.1","value1.1");
        document.formname.subcategory.options[1]=new Option("subcategory1.2","value1.2");
        document.formname.subcategory.options[2]=new Option("subcategory1.3","value1.3");
        break;

    case "category2" :
        document.formname.subcategory.options[0]=new Option("subcategory2.1","value2.1");
        document.formname.subcategory.options[1]=new Option("subcategory2.2","value2.2");
        document.formname.subcategory.options[2]=new Option("subcategory2.3","value2.3");
        break;

    case "category3" :
        document.formname.subcategory.options[0]=new Option("subcategory3.1","value3.1");
        document.formname.subcategory.options[1]=new Option("subcategory3.2","value3.2");
        document.formname.subcategory.options[2]=new Option("subcategory3.3","value3.3");
        break;

    default:
        document.formname.subcategory.options[0]=new Option("Select Category")
        break;
}
return true;
}
</script>
</head>

<title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>

<body>

<form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Category :</td>
<td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle"><select name="category" id="category" onchange="dropdownlist(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Select Category</option>
<option value="category1">category 1</option>
<option value="category2">category 2</option>
<option value="category3">category 3</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="middle">Sub Category :
</td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
document.write('<select name="subcategory"><option value="">Select Sub-Category</option></select>')
</script>
<noscript><select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >
<option value="">Select Sub-Category</option>
</select>
</noscript></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is pretty awesome, from my limited knowledge it looks right, let me try to work with it and figure it out, if it works I'll accept this answer, if not I'll ask for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: quick question, for "case "category1" :" should I change category1 to the value of the option in the drop down?

Comment: hmmm... I have just edited it. Get the code now go through and experiment!

Comment: will do :) I love learning like this, it may take me a while to get back to you, thanks :)

Comment: ok, another quick question, for subcategories I am using the javascript to insert the value of the option, but how do I get it to show the name as well?

Comment: oh no, i think you covered that in your edit, ok the edit confused me a bit, so the bit where it says option("sub...","value"); in the javascript is creating the value as well as the text that will be displayed correct? So in your example id change sub... to say "Web Design", "web_design" and the drop down for subcats would show "Web Design" and the value would register as web_design, correct?

Comment: ok, i did something wrong, its not showing the drop down, ill update the question to show what i did.

Comment: no, its not posting the code properly, anyways it isn't connecting the subcategory to the category correctly, it does say "Select Sub-Category as it should but there are no options.

Comment: I've accepted the answer, but it still isn't working, theoretically it should be perfect. I see the logic in that, but it isn't showing subcategories.

Answer (score 1):

Search for cascading dropdowns. This would Need to some JavaScript or maybe some server side code but with this search term you will find tons...

And start from here http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/drop-down

Comment: I googled cascading drop downs, and have found some interesting things, but nothing explaining how they work such as tutorials and so on, do you know of any good tutorials? What I am specifically trying to learn to do is say I have a site for people to sell graphics, the seller can click the category cms templates and the subcategory options are drupal, joomla, etc. but if they select web graphics then it will be icons, photos, etc...